# Can we get notification of answers to questions where we have offered bounties?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, bounties

I recently discovered that SE 2.0 lets me put bounties on other user's questions, so I tried offering bounties on a few of the questions on math.SE which I thought shouldn't still be open. So far, one is answered and one remains unclaimed, so that's good.

When the question I put a bounty on was answered, I didn't get a notification in the universal mailbox. (Whatever you call that thing in the upper left of the screen.) It seems to me that it would be better behavior if I got notification for these questions, since I cared enough to spend rep on them. I realize that watching the [bounties tab](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/448/david-speyer?tab=bounties) on my user page is an alternative, but not as convenient.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After the next build, you will be notified of any new answers on questions you have placed a bounty on.

We take care not to double notify someone when either:

- they own the question that has the bounty
- they are posting an answer on a question they started the bounty on