# How can I get updates for a question asked by another user?

Tags: feature-request

I am having an issue and was going to ask a question, but searched first and found an existing question about the same issue. So now I want to know whenever any answer or any updates comes to that question.

Is it possible? If yes, then how?

Comment: Make it a favourite by clicking on the star. Then you'll see if it's updated by visiting your favourites.

Comment: isn't is possible to get a mail or something when anyone posted any answer ?

Comment: A [bounty](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work) is a good way to attract attention to a question. And [you even get notified](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/108153/can-we-get-notification-of-answers-to-questions-where-we-have-offered-bounties) of answers to questions you have bountied.

Comment: This would be a nice feature, to get SO notifications to behave as if you asked the question. Favouriting has always seemed a bit weak to me

Comment: May be this question is a duplicate but still making it favourite does not notified that what actually been added in the question.

Comment: Nothing was added to this question, so there is nothing to notify you about.